# how to pass a list in to mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql, list, one-to-many, procedure, mysql-json

Do you want to insert one to many data at once(list of data) in mysql procedure, you can  use json method for that. then, you have to pass your list of data as a json by mysql json format. then you can insert list data using while loop.

Answer (score 0):

json object

```
{"billNo":16,"date":"2017-13-11 09:05:01","customerName":"Vikas","total":350.0,"fixedCharges":100,"taxAmount":25.78,"status":"paid","product":[{"productId":"MRR11","categoryId":72,"categoryName":"Parker Pen","cost":200,"quantity":2,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}},{"productId":"MRR12","categoryId":56,"categoryName":"Drawing Books","cost":150,"quantity":3,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}}]}
```

create procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `json_example1`(json_object JSON)
  BEGIN

        DECLARE products json;
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE categoryName VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 0;
        /*assign json_object's value to products mysql json object*/
        SELECT json_object->"$.product" INTO products;

        loop1 : WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(products) DO
                /*get categoryName from current products object in while loop */
                SET categoryName = JSON_EXTRACT(products,CONCAT('$[',i,'].categoryName'));
                /* insert categoryName into table */
                INSERT INTO product VALUES(NULL,SUBSTRING(categoryName,2,(LENGTH(categoryName)-2)));
                SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE loop1;
    END
```

call procedure

```
mysql> call json_example1('{"billNo":16,"date":"2017-13-11 09:05:01","customerName":"Vikas","total":350.0,"fixedCharges":100,"taxAmount":25.78,"status":"paid","product":[{"productId":"MRR11","categoryId":72,"categoryName":"Parker Pen","cost":200,"quantity":2,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}},{"productId":"MRR12","categoryId":56,"categoryName":"Drawing Books","cost":150,"quantity":3,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}}]}');
```

output

```
mysql> select * from product;
+------------+---------------+
| product_id | product_name  |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 | Parker Pen    |
|          2 | Drawing Books |
+------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

extra -

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;